# slidingDrawer with a viewFlipper INSIDE an other viewFlipper? possible?

Tags: android, viewflipper, gestures, slidingdrawer

Making a social media app. I have a main viewFlipper with several views therein. In this vf, I have a sliding drawer (containing a social media stream such as twitter and facebook) in which I want to place a second viewFlipper, so as to flip between the different medias.

Is this possible and how would be the simplest way of implementing it?

newbie question perhaps, but still! :D anyone want to help?

Comment: :( sadly my stack seems not to overflow...

Comment: seems this wasn't interesting enough... :D

Comment: +1 from me for your hilarious comment! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by making a fake drawer (a button that opens a new activity) and then placing a new flipper inside the new activity. this is what we in Sweden call "ett fulhack" (eng:an uglyhack). works, but not exactly as we want. :D

ty anyways!

Comment: :) I think it actually works pretty good, now that we've tested it out!